# Is it possible to squeeze all but N dimensions using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to know if there is a way to squeeze in one array all the dimensions of size 1, and leave N dimensions un-squeezed (even if those dimensions have size 1).

Why? Let say I have a function that receives one array and it return the matrix product of the array and its transpose, but the shape of the array is unknown (max of 2 dims with size > 1, but could have more dims with size 1)

Example of possible matrices shapes:

```
A.shape -> (M,N)
B.shape -> (M,N,1[...,1])
C.shape -> (M,1[...,1])
```

I want to have always the shape of A (ndim = 2) in order to perform the matrix product.

I could use `np.squeeze(X)`, and that's it, but in the case of C, this would lead to the following problem:

```
import numpy as np

def my_function(arr):
    arr = np.squeeze(arr)
    return np.dot(arr, arr.transpose())

x = np.arange(1, 6)  # shape (5,)
x = x.reshape((x.size, 1, 1))  # shape (5, 1, 1)
y = my_function(x)
print(y)
# Actual y.shape -> () [is a number]
# Expected y.shape -> (5, 5) [matrix]
```

I wish `np.squeeze()` function had a parameter `axis_to_keep`. Do you know if there is a way to achieve this easily? I know some ways to do it, but I need the most efficient way, because I have to do these operations several times.

Comment: Have you tried `np.squeeze(arr, -1)`?

Comment: @Chris yes, that would give me an error when the input shape is `(M, N)`, because the axis being squeezed is not of length 1. Also if I have input shape `(M, N, 1, 1, 1)` it would only squeeze the last axis, and I need to squeeze every axis but the first 2 (in this case).

Comment: Efficiency isn't much of an issue.  Shape changes like this just produce a view, which compared to copy and calculations is virtually costless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Squeeze with `axes_to_keep` param**

Here's one for generic n-dim arrays with the requested `axes_to_keep` param that keeps those axes in-place -

```
def squeeze_generic(a, axes_to_keep):
    out_s = [s for i,s in enumerate(a.shape) if i in axes_to_keep or s!=1]
    return a.reshape(out_s)
```

Sample runs -

```
In [105]: a = np.random.rand(3,4,5,1,1,6,1)

In [106]: squeeze_generic(a, axes_to_keep=(3,4)).shape
Out[106]: (3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 6)

In [107]: squeeze_generic(a, axes_to_keep=(3,4,6)).shape
Out[107]: (3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 6, 1)

# For cases when axes_to_keep lists axes that aren't singleton
In [108]: squeeze_generic(a, axes_to_keep=(0,1)).shape
Out[108]: (3, 4, 5, 6)
```

**Solving your case to keep first two axes**

Hence, to solve your specific case of keeping the first two axes, it would be -

```
squeeze_generic(a, axes_to_keep=range(2))
```

Let's look at the sample cases on this -

```
In [55]: a = np.random.rand(3,5)

In [56]: squeeze_generic(a, axes_to_keep=range(2)).shape
Out[56]: (3, 5)

In [57]: a = np.random.rand(3,5,1)

In [58]: squeeze_generic(a, axes_to_keep=range(2)).shape
Out[58]: (3, 5)

In [59]: a = np.random.rand(3,1)

In [60]: squeeze_generic(a, axes_to_keep=range(2)).shape
Out[60]: (3, 1)
```

If you are guaranteed to have all axes after the second one to be singleton (axis of length=1) if any, then a simple reshape does the job too -

```
a.reshape(a.shape[0],-1)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the best solution possible.

Answer (score 2):

One of the solutions I was thinking is the following:

```
def my_squeeze(arr, axis=None, keep=0):
    arr = np.squeeze(arr, axis=axis)
    while arr.ndim < keep:
        arr = np.expand_dims(arr, axis=-1)
    return arr
```

This function is working properly in the previous scenario:

```
def my_function(arr):
    arr = my_squeeze(arr, keep=2)
    return np.dot(arr, arr.transpose())

x = np.arange(5)
 x = x.reshape((x.size, 1, 1))
y = my_function(x)
print(y)  # shape -> (5, 5)
```

If anyone knows a better way to do it without creating a `my_squeeze()` function, I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: Look at the code for `expand_dims`.  Note how it constructs a tuple and uses it in `reshape`.  That's essentially what @Divakar is doing.

Comment: @hpaulj oh, I didn't expect that `expand_dims` would use `reshape`. I thought it would use something more "efficient". I guess my solution is not too good because of the while loop.

Comment: Nothing inefficient about `reshape` In most cases it produces a view with new shape and strides. No copy or element calculations.